# How to replace base url of a form action using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to make a simple search for Wikipedia where I can type what I want to search and a select where I can select the language. What I'm trying to do is to get the select value to be able to search in different languages so I just replace the language string in the url of wikipedia.org

(e.g. If I select French in the select dropdown the form should redirects me to fr.wikipedia.org and if I select English, it should redirects me to en.wikipedia.org)

Here's what I tried so far:

```php
<form id="searchWikipedia" action="" onsubmit="searchWikipedia()">
  <input id="search" name="search" type="text" />
  <select id="lang" name="language">
    <option value="en">English</option>
    <option value="fr">French</option>
  </select>
</form>

<script>
function searchWikipedia() {
  var select = document.getElementById("lang");
  var selectValue = select.options[select.selectedIndex].value;
  var searchValue = document.getElementById("search").value;

  document.getElementById("searchWikipedia").action = selectValue + ".wikipedia.org/w/index.php?search=" + searchValue;
  document.getElementById("searchWikipedia").submit();
}
</script>
```

Now, on submit I get this url: http://localhost/en.wikipedia.org/w/?search=cat

What I'm expecting is that the browser should redirect to en.wikipedia.org/w/?search=cat

How can I replace base url of a form action using JavaScript? Are there any better methods of doing this?

Answer (score 2):

you need to append the protocol at the start of the url or the browser will take it as a relative url to your document.

```html
<form id="searchWikipedia" action="" onsubmit="searchWikipedia()">
  <input id="search" name="search" type="text" />
  <select id="lang" name="language">
    <option value="en">English</option>
    <option value="fr">French</option>
  </select>
</form>

<script>
function searchWikipedia() {
  var select = document.getElementById("lang");
  var selectValue = select.options[select.selectedIndex].value;
  var searchValue = document.getElementById("search").value;

  // append https at the start
  document.getElementById("searchWikipedia").action = "https://" + selectValue + ".wikipedia.org/w/index.php?search=" + searchValue;
  document.getElementById("searchWikipedia").submit();
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Add Submit input tag, to perform action

```html
<form id="searchWikipedia" action="" onsubmit="searchWikipedia(event)">
    <input id="search" name="search" type="text" />
    <select id="lang" name="language">
      <option value="en">English</option>
      <option value="fr">French</option>
    </select>
    <input type="submit" value="Search">
  </form>
  <script>
    function searchWikipedia(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var select = document.getElementById("lang");
    var selectValue = select.options[select.selectedIndex].value;
    var searchValue = document.getElementById("search").value;
    
  // it will open new tab 
window.open("https://" +  selectValue + ".wikipedia.org/w/index.php?search=" + searchValue);

// if you want to replace same url then use this
// window.location.replace(`https://${selectValue}.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?search=${searchValue}`);

  }
  </script>
```

I think, it will be helpful for you.